# Do I need to be in range of a PokéStop to gain the benefit of a Lure Module?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a PokéStop outside of my building. It's not far at all, but it's just far enough away that I am not in range of it while inside. I have to go downstairs and walk about 50 feet to get in range (also it's raining right now!)

If I go outside and set a Lure Module on the PokéStop, would I still gain the benefit of increased Pokémon appearances while just outside of the interaction range?

For reference, here is a screenshot of my map to illustrate my situation.

[image]

Comment: Im just amazed that you sre level 8 while im stuck at 4 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll gain the increased appearance bonus when you are inside the circle of influence of the pokemon stop with the lure module activated.

http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Lure_Modules

Comment: During my playtime this past weekend I think I have anecdotally confirmed this. Until some hard facts to the contrary come to light, this seems to be the correct answer (unfortunately for me).

Comment: That link doesn't support the answer you provided. The word influence only appears once, "When deployed, any PokeStop under the influence can be seen on the map with a shower of pink petals around the stop".

Comment: It is kind of inferred that it is within the influence since the petals have a similar radius of the range you need to be to activate the pokestop.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the lure module causes pokemon to spawn more often in the area of influence around the pokestop. If you are close enough that your circle covers part of the area of influence of the pokestop, then you would get a partial benefit from the lure from any pokemon that spawned in that overlap.

I can't find any official information detailing the mechanics behind a lure module so I only have my personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you walk over there every ~5 - 15 minutes. The Pokemon will spawn within the area of the lure module and stay there for a while. You can check this by finding a stop with a lure that has been active for a while, usually you will find that 2-3 Pokemon are there. You could wait the ~15 minutes (1 ever ~5 minutes) for 3 Pokemon to spawn and walk the 50 feet to catch them, but you don't have to be in range of the stop for them to spawn. I don't know the exact de-spawn rate, but i wouldn't wait more than 15 minutes as i haven't seen more than 3 at any one module. 
Source: I don't have a life.